# Nativescript 6 code sharing project and lazy loaded modules

Tags: webpack, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm having problems compiling a NS 6 code sharing project with a lazy loaded module.

I add it to the routes in this way:

```
{ path: 'onboarding', loadChildren: './onboarding/onboarding.module#OnboardingModule' },
```

This has always worked both in Angular CLI projects but also in the Non-Code Sharing NS projects.

However, in this case I'm getting this error:

```
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: /Users/denny/workspaceNW/gesso-app/src/app/onboarding/onboarding.module.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at NativeScriptAngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/Users/denny/workspaceNW/gesso-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:838:23)
    at NativeScriptAngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/Users/denny/workspaceNW/gesso-app/node_modules/nativescript-dev-webpack/plugins/NativeScriptAngularCompilerPlugin.js:28:26)
    at plugin.done.then (/Users/denny/workspaceNW/gesso-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:41:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
 @ ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object ./onboarding/onboarding.module
 @ ../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
 @ ./main.tns.ts
```

I am able to fix it by adding the module file in the "files" section of `tsconfig.tns.json` but I'm wondering if that's the right way to do it:

```
"files": [
    "src/main.tns.ts",
    "src/app/onboarding/onboarding.module.ts"
]
```

Anybody has had the same issue? I'm using the latest version of Nativescript:

```
tns info
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 6.0.3 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-core-modules has 6.0.7 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-android has 6.0.2 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-ios has 6.0.2 version and is up to date.
```

I've also tried to update the `nativescript-dev-webpack` package to `~1.1.1`, same result.

Comment: Is it being imported in app or routing module - `./onboarding/onboarding.module`?

Comment: No, I use the `loadChildren` string for lazy loaded modules, if I import it then there is no lazy loading I suppose, I'll update the question with the route section